# Combine several command in one shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, command

I only can get the desire output when I run the command one by one. How can I combine all the command in a shell script and get the desired output?

```
//insert timestamp column
$ vmstat -n 5 | (while read; do echo "$(date +%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S) $REPLY"; done)> vm.txt 
//remove 1st & 2nd row
$ sed '1,2d' vm.txt > vm2.txt 
//convert text file to csv
$ sed 's/^  *//;s/  */,/g'  vm2.txt > vm2.csv 
//insert column name
$ echo $'datetime, r, b, swpd, free, buff, cache, si, so, bi, bo, in, cs, us, sy, id, wa, st' | cat - vm2.csv> chart.csv
$ psql -p 5432 -U postgres -c  "\copy vmstat FROM '/root/report/chart.csv' delimiter '|' csv header"
```

Comment: put the commands to a script, and run the script...

Comment: How many lines do you need from `vmstat` (I'm assuming you are manually interrupting the command now)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all your commands in a file, let say myCommands.
Note the `#!/bin/sh` at the first line.
That is called a shebang, it tells the shell what program to interpret the script with, when executed.

```
#!/bin/sh
# insert timestamp column
vmstat -n 5 | (while read; do echo "$(date +%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S) $REPLY"; done)> vm.txt 
# remove 1st & 2nd row
sed '1,2d' vm.txt > vm2.txt 
# convert text file to csv
sed 's/^  *//;s/  */,/g'  vm2.txt > vm2.csv 
# insert column name
echo $'datetime, r, b, swpd, free, buff, cache, si, so, bi, bo, in, cs, us, sy, id, wa, st' | cat - vm2.csv> chart.csv
psql -p 5432 -U postgres -c  "\copy vmstat FROM '/root/report/chart.csv' delimiter '|' csv header"
```

Next, make it executable:

`chmod +x myCommands`

Now, you can use it either by using `./myCommands` if you are in the same folder,
or symply `myCommands` if the script file is in a older included in the `$PATH` variable.

Comment: I try like what you said but I only able to get the text file.

Comment: @Fayne It's a bit unclear what you expect to get.

Comment: At the last, I need to get csv file and the data inside the csv file need to be copied into my database.

Comment: @Fayne That is what the above script is doing, assuming it is run from `/root/report`.

Comment: @Fayne It seems that `vmstat` keeps running indefinitely. That would explain why you are only getting the text file. How many output lines of `vmstat` do you need?

Comment: @nxnev 100 lines

Comment: @Fayne Then just modify the first command to get as many lines as you want. For example: `vmstat -n 5 | for i in {1..101}; do read; echo "$(date +%Y-%m-%d.%H:%M:%S) $REPLY"; done`. The first line is the header, so you may actually need 101 lines.

Comment: @Fayne, you should **accept** the answer if it solved your problem. Please, [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how to use this site.

Answer (score 1):

The following script will do the equivalent things that your commands are doing, but without creating so many intermediate files:

```
#!/bin/sh

report=/root/report/chart.csv

vmstat -n 5 100 |
awk -vOFS=',' 'NR == 1 { next }
               NR == 2 { $1 = "datetime" OFS $1 }
               NR  > 2 { $1 = strftime("%F.%T", systime()) OFS $1 } 1' >"$report"

psql -p 5432 -U postgres -c "COPY vmstat FROM '$report' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER"
```

This uses a single `awk` script to insert the datestamp column at the start and to convert the output to comma-delimited records.  It reuses the header outputted from `vmstat` and collects 100 lines of `vmstat` output with a five second interval. I have also changed the delimiter used in the PostrgeSQL statement to a comma, as that's what the data is using.

The script expects that `awk` is GNU `awk` as found on most Linux systems.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda . It works. Can you explain the commands as well? Cause I still didn't get it how you remove the header of the file

Comment: It seems that the last part can't work. If there any other solution to copy to database?

Comment: @Fayne It's the same command that you used (except for the changed delimiter), so if your command worked, this command would also work. How are you seeing that it does not?